# error: called object is not a function or function pointer. my * symbol causes the error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Here is my code that shows "error: called object is not a function or function pointer." My * symbol causes the error. I'm new at using C language, so I'm still confused. Please help me. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char typeOfBeam;
    float B;
    float H;
    float b;
    float h;
    float pi = 3.14159265;
    float r;
    float momentOfInertia;
    float I = momentOfInertia;
    float iBeam = ((B * H)(B * H)(B * H) - (b * h)(b * h)(b * h)) / 12;
    float rectangularBeam = ((b * h)(b * h)(b * h)) / 12;
    float cylindricalBeam = ((pi * r)(pi * r)(pi * r)(pi * r)) / 4;
    
    printf("Enter type of beam: ");
    scanf("%c", &typeOfBeam);
    if (typeOfBeam = iBeam)
    {
        printf("Enter Width: ");
        scanf("%f", &B);
        printf("Enter Flange-Flange Inner Face Height: ");
        scanf("%f", &H);
        printf("Enter Web Thickness: ");
        scanf("%f", &b);
        printf("Enter Flange Thickness: ");
        scanf("%f", &h);
        printf("The answer is: %f", iBeam);
    }
    else if (typeOfBeam = rectangularBeam)
    {
        printf("Enter Web Thickness: ");
        scanf("%f", &b);
        printf("Enter Flange Thickness: ");
        scanf("%f", &h);
        printf("The answer is: %f", rectangularBeam);
    }
    else if (typeOfBeam = cylindricalBeam)
    {
        printf("Enter Radius: ");
        scanf("%f", &r);
        printf("The answer is: %f", cylindricalBeam);
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid input.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You assign rather than compare in your if tests.  That isn't the immediate source of your error though.

Comment: The error msg should have a line number. Please give us that info.

Comment: Your computations before the input are working with uninitialized variables.  That is bad too.  You'll need to move the calculations after you've read the data.

Comment: I'll take note of that, but I still get that error even though I put the iBeam, rectangularBeam and cylindricalBeam anywhere in my code. But still, thank you.

Comment: I'm getting the error in line 14, 15 and 16.

Comment: There are lot of uninitialized variable and you are playing with them, not okay! For e.g here `float iBeam = ((B * H)(B * H)(B * H) - (b * h)(b * h)(b * h)) / 12;` variables `B`, `H`, `b`, and `h` contains junk value default, what is expectation of multiplying junk values ?

Comment: `(B * H)(B * H)(B * H)` You need to put `*` in between the expressions. `(B * H) * (B * H) * (B * H)`, etc. But apart from those syntax errors, the code has lots of logical errors as noted by the other comments.

Comment: As pointed by @kaylum `(B * H)(B * H)(B * H)` is not a valid `C` expression. You need to use `*` here if intention is to multiply. for e.g `(B * H) * (B * H) * (B * H)`

Comment: I'm so sorry if my code is messy @Achal. I'm new to C and in programming as well. I'll take note of your comment. Thank you!

Comment: @kaylum Thank you!!! My error is gone now. It's so embarassing that I forgot those * in the middle of my parentheses. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. For further question it would be a good idea to remove all code that is not relevant. In this case you could probable remove everything after line 16 and still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

regarding;

```
float pi = 3.14159265;
```

This is trying to assign a `float` from a `double` literal. Much better to write:

```
float pi = 3.14159265f;
```

Note the trailing 'f' that declares the literal as a `float`

regarding:

```
if (typeOfBeam = iBeam)
```

This is an assignment due to the single `=`. Suggest:

```
if (typeOfBeam == iBeam)
```

Notice the == which is a comparison

regarding;

```
float iBeam = ((B * H)(B * H)(B * H) - (b * h)(b * h)(b * h)) / 12;
```

and

```
if (typeOfBeam = iBeam)
```

the iBeam cannot be both a `char` and a `float`

The same considerations exist for: `rectangularBeam` and `cylindricalBeam`

regarding:

```
float I = momentOfInertia;
```

the variable: `momentOfInertia` has not been initialized to a 'known' value.  So this statement results in Undefined Behavior.

regarding:

```
float iBeam = ((B * H)(B * H)(B * H) - (b * h)(b * h)(b * h)) / 12;
float rectangularBeam = ((b * h)(b * h)(b * h)) / 12;
float cylindricalBeam = ((pi * r)(pi * r)(pi * r)(pi * r)) / 4;
```

since the variables:  B`,` H`, 'b`, and `h` are not initialized to 'known' values, these statements result in Undefined Behavior.  Remember that execution is performed in a 'linear' fashion so the content of variables must not used until after the variables are set to 'known' values.

regarding the `4` and the `12`:  The statements are working with `float` values, so the literals should also be `float`.  Suggest the literals be written as: `4.0f` and `12.0f`.

When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  (there are lots of ways the user can cause this function to fail.)

Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful `input format conversion` specifiers (or EOF).  Since all the calls to `scanf()` in the current code have exactly 1 `input format conversion` specifier, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.